# Additional web page with flexible access control in Moodle

Tags: php, authorization, moodle

In Moodle 2.6 I created a new web page `external.php` and copied it into the root folder on server. The web page contains an activity (my own HTML and JavaScript) that must be accessible for the participants of definite courses. I have 3 courses now (let's call them A, B and C) and I want the content of the web page to be visible for the participants of A and B, but not for the participants of C.

So far I managed to limit the access with `isloggedin()` and it works fine, but that is only a compromise.

**So my question is**: Is it possible to limit the access to this web page (it is not a part of a course and not intended to be) to the participants of course A and B, but not C?

This is the code of my `external.php`:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
// Open the page if the user is logged in
if (isloggedin()) {
    $PAGE->set_context(get_system_context());
    $PAGE->set_pagelayout('standart');
    $PAGE->set_title("Experimental page");
    $PAGE->set_heading("External");
    $PAGE->set_url($CFG->wwwroot . '/external.php');

    // Adding navbar
    $PAGE->navbar->ignore_active();
    $strHome = "important";
    $PAGE->navbar->add($strHome, new moodle_url('external.php'));

    echo $OUTPUT->header();

    // Variables for the content (html and javascript)
    $jscr = ""; // some code
    $htmlscr = ""; // some code

    // Actual content goes here
    echo $htmlscr;
    echo $jscr;
    echo $OUTPUT->footer();
}
// Else output error message
else {
    echo "<h2>Please log in to procede</h2>";
}
?>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of searching in the documentation and asking experienced people I could find the solution.

I replaced:

```
if (isloggedin()) {
    MY CODE INSIDE
}
```

with:

```
if ((is_enrolled(context_course::instance(18), $USER)) or (is_enrolled(context_course::instance(20), $USER)) or is_siteadmin()) {
    MY CODE INSIDE
}
```

This code gives access to MY CODE INSIDE to the students enrolled into the courses with id **18** and **20** and to the **administrator**.

The course id can be found in the browser address bar when the course main page is open.

I hope it will be helpful for other Moodle administrators.